# How do I make buttons not fall down when opening their contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the buttons to be on top at all times, and when i click one of them i want the contents to appear below WITHOUT pushing other buttons below

`here is the fiddle`
https://jsfiddle.net/9fk5r3v7/

sry about the openload, it can be anything, just a placeholder 4 now

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] with a sample of the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make the buttons before the divs

Check this: jsfiddle.net/ajtehs4y/

Answer (score 1):

The order of your elements is causing this, because the divs are inbetween the buttons, when one is shown it pushes the button after it onto a new line.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrwrbnsn/k92mpyad/)

```
<button type="button" name="cat"><img src="cat.jpeg" /></button>
<button type="button" name="dog"><img src="dog.jpeg" /></button>
<button type="button" name="dog2"><img src="dog.jpeg" /></button>
<button type="button" name="dog3"><img src="dog.jpeg" /></button>

<!-- dropdown content goes after the buttons -->

<div id="catdiv" class="hide">
<!-- Content here -->
</div>
<div id="dogdiv" class="hide">
<!-- Content here -->
</div>
<div id="dog2div" class="hide">
<!-- Content here -->
</div>
<div id="dog3div" class="hide">
<!-- Content here -->
</div>
```